# Why squid can't connect to openstreetmap.org over tls?

Tags: ssl, openstreetmap, squid

I'd like to configure squid as reverse proxy do tile.openstreetmap.org. I did it like in example from OSM wiki:

```
cache_peer tile.openstreetmap.org parent 80 0 no-query no-digest originserver name=osmTiles forceddomain=tile.openstreetmap.org
```

and it works fine. However I can't manage to use https. From Firefox, I can access tile without any problem, but squid with the following configuration fails:

```
cache_peer a.tile.openstreetmap.org parent 443 0 no-query originserver name=osmTiles forceddomain=tile.openstreetmap.org tls

127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2024:19:58:53 +0100] "GET http://localhost:81/7/68/34.png HTTP/1.1" 503 4560 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0" TCP_MISS:FIRSTUP_PARENT
```

tshark shows:

```
    1 0.000000000 192.168.2.99 → 151.101.65.91 TCP 74 47964 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2746695547 TSecr=0 WS=1024
    2 0.022873501 151.101.65.91 → 192.168.2.99 TCP 74 443 → 47964 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1452 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=3221760153 TSecr=2746695547 WS=512
    3 0.022928676 192.168.2.99 → 151.101.65.91 TCP 66 47964 → 443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64512 Len=0 TSval=2746695570 TSecr=3221760153
    4 0.023287990 192.168.2.99 → 151.101.65.91 TLSv1 439 Client Hello
    5 0.045903479 151.101.65.91 → 192.168.2.99 TCP 66 443 → 47964 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=374 Win=145920 Len=0 TSval=3221760176 TSecr=2746695570
    6 0.053252749 151.101.65.91 → 192.168.2.99 TLSv1.3 2946 Server Hello, Change Cipher Spec, Application Data
    7 0.053252879 151.101.65.91 → 192.168.2.99 TCP 1506 443 → 47964 [ACK] Seq=2881 Ack=374 Win=145920 Len=1440 TSval=3221760183 TSecr=2746695570 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    8 0.053317903 192.168.2.99 → 151.101.65.91 TCP 66 47964 → 443 [ACK] Seq=374 Ack=2881 Win=63488 Len=0 TSval=2746695600 TSecr=3221760183
    9 0.053362187 192.168.2.99 → 151.101.65.91 TCP 66 47964 → 443 [ACK] Seq=374 Ack=4321 Win=63488 Len=0 TSval=2746695600 TSecr=3221760183
   10 0.053388337 151.101.65.91 → 192.168.2.99 TLSv1.3 842 Application Data, Application Data, Application Data, Application Data
   11 0.053395841 192.168.2.99 → 151.101.65.91 TCP 66 47964 → 443 [ACK] Seq=374 Ack=5097 Win=63488 Len=0 TSval=2746695600 TSecr=3221760183
   12 0.053826341 192.168.2.99 → 151.101.65.91 TLSv1.3 72 Change Cipher Spec
   13 0.054322064 192.168.2.99 → 151.101.65.91 TLSv1.3 124 Application Data
   14 0.054638647 192.168.2.99 → 151.101.65.91 TLSv1.3 897 Application Data
   15 0.054709442 192.168.2.99 → 151.101.65.91 TLSv1.3 90 Application Data
   16 0.054769536 192.168.2.99 → 151.101.65.91 TCP 66 47964 → 443 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1293 Ack=5097 Win=64512 Len=0 TSval=2746695602 TSecr=3221760183
   ***** Why FIN here ?                                            ^^^
   17 0.076868403 151.101.65.91 → 192.168.2.99 TCP 66 443 → 47964 [ACK] Seq=5097 Ack=380 Win=145920 Len=0 TSval=3221760207 TSecr=2746695601
   18 0.076868543 151.101.65.91 → 192.168.2.99 TCP 66 443 → 47964 [ACK] Seq=5097 Ack=438 Win=145920 Len=0 TSval=3221760207 TSecr=2746695601
   19 0.077931347 151.101.65.91 → 192.168.2.99 TCP 66 443 → 47964 [ACK] Seq=5097 Ack=1269 Win=147968 Len=0 TSval=3221760208 TSecr=2746695602
   20 0.077931427 151.101.65.91 → 192.168.2.99 TCP 66 443 → 47964 [ACK] Seq=5097 Ack=1293 Win=147968 Len=0 TSval=3221760208 TSecr=2746695602
   21 0.077931497 151.101.65.91 → 192.168.2.99 TCP 66 443 → 47964 [ACK] Seq=5097 Ack=1294 Win=147968 Len=0 TSval=3221760208 TSecr=2746695602
   22 0.078014515 151.101.65.91 → 192.168.2.99 TLSv1.3 90 Application Data
   23 0.078029574 192.168.2.99 → 151.101.65.91 TCP 54 47964 → 443 [RST] Seq=1294 Win=0 Len=0
   24 0.078044101 151.101.65.91 → 192.168.2.99 TCP 66 443 → 47964 [FIN, ACK] Seq=5121 Ack=1294 Win=147968 Len=0 TSval=3221760208 TSecr=2746695602
   25 0.078051335 192.168.2.99 → 151.101.65.91 TCP 54 47964 → 443 [RST] Seq=1294 Win=0 Len=0
```